# Datagrid cell background color binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datagrid, background

I have a DataGrid and need to set individual background colors on some cells and change the color of the cell on selection.
Changing the color on selection works well and if try setting the background color without binding it works, too.  I assume my binding is wrong.

Therefore i used this code in xaml

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="NumberCell">

        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor},Path=StatusColor}"></Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource LoudBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource LoudBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

my code for populating the datagrid:

```
private void AddColumns(DataGrid dataGrid, IEnumerable<User> Users)
    {


       var columnsAmount =  dataGrid.Columns.Count;
       if(columnsAmount > 1)
       {
           var dayColumnKepper = dataGrid.Columns[0];
           dataGrid.Columns.Clear();
           dataGrid.Columns.Insert(0, dayColumnKepper);
       }

        foreach(var user in Users)
        {
            var column = new DataGridTextColumn();
            column.Binding = new Binding(string.Format("UserWorkplan[{0}].Appointment.Type", user.Id));
            column.Header = user.Username;
            column.CellStyle = (Style)Resources["NumberCell"];
            dataGrid.Columns.Insert(1, column);
        }
    }

public IDictionary<int, CalenderWorkplanEntry> UserWorkplan { get; set; }
```

StatusColor should be the color of the individual row, but the color is always the datagrid default color.

```
public class CalenderWorkplanEntry
{

    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string StatusColor { get; set; }
    public WorkPlanAppointment Appointment { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

First things first... please do yourself a favour and do *not* manipulate UI objects in the code behind. The correct way to bind to a collection control is to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface, define a public `ObservableCollection<T>` property and to data bind it to the `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" />
```

Next, to get rid of the default selection colours, add this into your `Resources` section:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

You can play around with these colours to suit your requirements, or just leave them as `Transparent` so that they do not hide your `Trigger` colours.

Please let me know if I have misunderstood your problem.

Comment: the trigger work well, but next time i will use your approach for. I thing my problem is in this line: <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor},Path=StatusColor}"></Setter>. I contains the color of every row, but every time default color is displayed.

Comment: Yeah, that `Binding` is invalid... what are you trying to bind to?

Comment: in CalenderWorkplanEntry has a string StatusColor and i want to bind StatusColor to the style.setter.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think that I can help you with this... you're doing it in such a messed up way. Had you done this in the normal WPF way, then the fix would be simple... as it is... not so simple. Normally, you'd bind a collection of items to the `ItemsSource` property - this gives you one item per row and all of the columns have access to that row of data. Your code messes that up. Furthermore, it is more usual to create a data type that contains *all* of the properties that are required in the UI, but you're using this `IDictionary` which is just making everything more tricky. Sorry.